# Where method converts hashtable to collection

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell I have a list of hashtables.  I've used a `Where()` method to select one of the hashtables in the list because I read that `Where()` is faster than `Where-Object`.  However, when I try to operate on the selected hashtable I find it's been converted to a Collection by the `Where()` method.  I can't cast it back to a hashtable.

Is there any way to get the `Where()` method to return a hashtable instead of a Collection?

If I have to I can use `Where-Object` which does return a hashtable.  However, I'd prefer to stick with `Where()` if there is a simple workaround.

Some demo code:

```
Clear-Host

[System.Object[]]$SqlServers = @(
                                    @{
                                        key="L"; 
                                        connectionString="Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=yes;";
                                    },
                                    @{
                                        key="D"; 
                                        connectionString="Server=DEV.DEV.LOCAL;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=yes;";
                                    }
                                )
$UserSelection = 'L'

$selectedServerDetails = $SqlServers.Where({$_.key -eq $UserSelection})
$selectedServerDetails2 = $SqlServers | Where-Object{$_.key -eq $UserSelection}

$selectedServerDetails3 = ($selectedServerDetails -as [hashtable])

$selectedServerDetails.GetType().FullName
$selectedServerDetails2.GetType().FullName
if ($selectedServerDetails3 -eq $null) { '$selectedServerDetails3 is null' } else { $selectedServerDetails3.GetType().FullName }
```

Which results in:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Management.Automation.PSObject, System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]
System.Collections.Hashtable
$selectedServerDetails3 is null
```

By the way, I tried changing the data type of `$SqlServers` to `[hashtable[]]$SqlServers`.  It made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) *cmdlet*, **the [intrinsic `.Where()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) *always* returns a [*collection*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection-1) - even if only *one* element of the input collection matches**; the same applies analogously to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) vs. the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach).

- As an aside: Unlike `Where-Object`, `.Where()` offers an *optimization* via its optional second parameter: `'First'` *short-circuits* the filtering by immediately returning once the first match is found - this optimization is applied below.
- The unfortunate asymmetry of `Where-Object` *not* offering the same short-circuiting is the subject of the feature request in [GitHub issue #13834](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13834).

Additionally, each matching element is wrapped in a *mostly* invisible `[psobject]` wrapper.

- Unfortunately, there are cases where this meant-to-be-an-invisible-implementation-detail `[psobject]` wrapper *does* cause a difference in behavior - see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).

Therefore, simply **use *indexing*** to extract the (only) matching element, i.e. `[0]`:

```
$selectedServerDetails =
  $SqlServers.Where({$_.key -eq $UserSelection}, 'First')[0]
```

To rule out potential side effects from the invisible `[psobject]` wrapper, use the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views), via the `.BaseObject` property, to extract the wrapped .NET object:

```
$selectedServerDetails = 
  $SqlServers.Where({$_.key -eq $UserSelection}, 'First')[0].psobject.BaseObject
```